# Find Two Words on url string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find two words on urls, it looks like the underscore don't allow the word be found

> http://www.example.com/image/med_crop/photo.jpg
>
> http://www.example.com/image/medium/photo.jpg

```
/\bmedium\b|\wmed_crop\w/i
```

> http://regex101.com/r/wI5oF7/1

Comment: Why are you using `\w` around med_prop? `/` is most likely not matched by `\w`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use the `\w` around the "med_crop". \w only matches [a-zA-Z0-9_], not the slashes. Also, you will need to use the global modifier `g` if you want to match more than one at a time.

This seems to work in your example

```
/\bmedium\b|\bmed_crop\b/ig
```

Comment: I've already tried \b so I was testing \w without success. I see the problem was global. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, JavaScript only matches the first occurrence by default. The matching processing engine defaults to doing the least work needed. `g` instructs it to continue on and find all matches.